# Could any complications arise if the two FMCs are using different OPS programmes, i.e U10.7 and U10.8A?

Tags: safety

B737-300
FMCs ARE OF SMITH INDUSTRIES 2907a4/10-6225-003

Comment: You should explicit technical terms you use. Although the community here is expert in aviation, this field is huge and no one can be expert in all subfields. Thus you may at least provide links to explain all references.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't work. The two FMC's need to communicate & stay in sync; that process requires the same OFP in both.